# Using C# DLL in managed C++ (command line)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli, interop

I've looked over a few questions with a title just like this one, but they either do not talk about command line, or don't seem to work for me for some reason. From what I have read, it seemed as if I could "simply" do the following:

The dummy code (C#):

```
using System;

public static class Foo {
    public static void Bar() {
        Console.WriteLine("o3o");
    }
}
```

More dummy code (Visual C++):

```
#using <test.dll>

int main() {
    Foo::Bar();
    return 0;
}
```

C# DLL compiled using:

```
csc /out:test.dll /t:library src\cs\Foo.cs
```

Visual C++ object file compiled using:

```
cl /Ox /clr /AI. /c src\vc\test.cpp
```

Executable compiled using:

```
link /out:test.exe test.obj
```

The following exception is thrown upon running the executable:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Foo' from assembly 'test, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at main()
   at mainCRTStartup()
```

I have a strong feeling that I was supposed to also reference the DLL in the link phase, but I couldn't find any option for linking a DLL similar to GCC's `-l` option. Attempting to pass the DLL along with the `.obj` to `link` causes it to tell me that linking assemblies is not supported. Interestingly, though, if I build a `.netmodule` instead of a DLL, i.e. by:

```
csc /out:test.dll /t:module src\cs\Foo.cs
```

and changing the `#using` directive to

```
#using <test.netmodule>
```

the executable runs without error. This feels a bit weird, for I don't think anybody packages code in `.netmodule`s (what *are* `.netmodule`s, anyway?).

Comment: Think of a `.netmodule` as the equivalent of a `.lib` in plain C++, that's why you can link with it. Managed code is somewhat different, you don't just link `.dll` files together. Why are you trying to link them in the first place? Your C++/CLI exe can just reference the C# dll without linking with it, just put the dll in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: The DLL does reside in the same directory as the executable, but the aforementioned exception is thrown upon running it.

Comment: Ok I looked at the issue and posted an answer. I just wanted to make sure you didn't get caught by the #1 trap when mixing C# and C++/CLI first :) (the default configuration of the IDE is kind of broken - it makes it hard to do this for no reason by not putting the output files in the same place - as you have used directories in your commands I figured you could have had the same issue, but then I realized what `/AI.` was)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your steps should have worked, but one very simple issue is preventing your program from running.

Namely: Your C# DLL assembly name is `test`, and your C++/CLI exe assembly has the same name. They both have the same identity.

So when looking for `Foo::Bar` in the `test` assembly, the loader first checks if the assembly is loaded in the AppDomain. It is - it's your C++/CLI exe, and you can't have several assemblies with the same identity loaded simultaneously within the same AppDomain. Your C# dll wasn't even given a try.

Just change either one of them and everything will work fine:

```
link /out:test2.exe test.obj
```

---

As for what's a `.netmodule`, it's the format used for linking managed code statically, that's why you managed to link your C# code with your C++/CLI code without issues. It's *roughly* the equivalent of a `.lib` file for managed code.
And you're right, it's not used very often.